# How to force a member function's argument to a specific type

Tags: types, f#

I wrote a small F# library while messing around that contains a few math functions like the following:

```
namespace MyLib

type Math() =
    member this.add(a,b) =
        a+b
```

Now, I am trying to call it from C# like:

```
using System;
using MyLib;

class Test {
   static void main(string[] args) {
      Double sum = MyLib.add(1.2, 3.5)
      Console.WriteLine(sum.ToString());
   }
}
```

This code gives me an error, When I look at the function's signature, I see that it accepts two integers.

The reason I am using `Double`s is because in another function, I am using F# exponentiation. How can I tell an F# function that it should accept `Double`s as apposed to `int`s

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just add a type annotation explicitly:

```
type Math() =
    member this.add(a:float,b:float) =
        a+b
```

(note that `System.Double` is called `float` in F#)

Comment: and C# will not confuse that with a `System.Float`?